# Single Foreign Key for multiple look up tables

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a simple application that would record several widget selections within a form (drop-down list and multiple select for this example) and save it within a log table in a small database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/THpfs.png

This schema represents a selection of a Fruit from a drop down, and 1-n Fruit Type Selection from a multi-select:

Fruit

    `FruitId     Name
    1           Apple
    2           Orange
    3           Melon`

Orange

     `OrangeId     Name     PLU1     PLU2
     1            Navel    123      321
     2            Blood    213      412
     3            Cara     512      433`

LogFruitSelection

     `LogId     FruitId     FruitSelection
     1         2           2
     1         2           3
     2         1           1
     2         1           2
     2         1           3
     2         1           4`

The user is restricted to select only one fruit which will give them an option to select multiple types of that fruit, 1 type of fruit per submission. The selections will be held within a selection table which will reference a LogId, a FruitId, and a SelectionId which references a lookup table.

I am lost as to how to create a schema that would let me use a selection table with a single foreign key that would reference several look up tables based on another columns value.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: rename Orange table to fruit type and add a column fruit_id which references fruit table.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want

Fruit

```
 FruitId     Name
    1           Apple
    2           Orange
    3           Melon
```

Fruit Type

```
 TypeId     Name     PLU1     PLU2  FruitId
 1            Navel    123      321  2
 2            Blood    213      412  2
 3            Cara     512      433  2
```

LogFruitSelection

```
 LogId     FruitId     FruitSelection
 1         2           2
 1         2           3
 2         1           1
 2         1           2
 2         1           3
 2         1           4
```